# Little icon to add an image to a text area not showing except for one uses

Tags: image, drupal, directory

I recently installed IMCE to allow inserting images into text areas from folders on the server.* It works great for me, but other administrators cannot get the icon in the image dialog box. I have checked the permissions and administrators have permissions set for all functions. I have also cleared the cache. We have tried on multiple computers, including I have logged out and had other administrators log in on my computer with the same results. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

- For anyone who hasn't used this function, the icon mentioned shows up when 1) you click the little tree icon in the WYSIWIG, 2) look to the right of the field called Image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it only took two weeks, but I figured out the answer to my own problem. The problem was that the Administrator Role did not have file browsing capabilities. By going to the IMCE Media configuration, I was able to give the Administrator Role access to the User-1 public files.